# Unable to login to my remote server using ssh even after providing correct public and private keys

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I recently moved away from my windows machine and am now on ubuntu 18.04, however, whenever I try logging in to my remote servers using `ssh <username>@<serverIp>`, I get a **Permission denied (public key)** error. In my opinion, If I am using the same public and private keys, it should have worked, not sure what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Did you add the contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` from the client to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server?

Comment: Shouldn't it already be there since I was logging in using the same key, just a difference pc.

Comment: You need to make sure that the `id_rsa.pub` or whatever pub key you are using on the client matches exactly in the `authorized_keys` in the server.  All the way to the PC name itself.  Also, make sure that the permissions on the key files are correct at `rw-------` or `chmod 600 filename`.  Open permissions can cause failures in connecting as well.

Comment: additionally run `ssh -vv user@host` and [edit] your post to include this. This contains debug info about which keys were tried, and possibly why they were refused.

Comment: sure, let me upload the results here.

Comment: worked, the file permissions were incorrect. changed it to 600, worked.
@Terrance, could you help me understand what exactly the problem might have been?

Comment: Wrote you an answer.  Hope that helps!  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions on the key files are too open.  They need to be set to owner only.  `ssh` requires that the permissions be set to the owner only for security reasons.  Too open of permissions like `664`, `644`, etc can cause `ssh` to fail with the error of permissions.

The following will set the permissions to Read / Write or `rw-------` for the owner only:

```
chmod 600 id_rsa
chmod 600 id_rsa.pub
chmod 600 authorized_keys
```

You can even set the `id_rsa` and the `id_rsa.pub` to Read Only with a permission of `400` or `r--------`.  I recommend leaving the `authorized_keys` and `known_hosts` at `600` just in case you need to add another key to it from another computer.